# Finding the length of the longest streak of ones in any array

Tags: c++, array

I need help reviewing my code snippet copied below. 
The below code counts the number of continuous ones in a given array of Size 11.

```
#define size 11
#define ONE 1
using namespace std;

#include <iostream> 
#include "stdio.h"

    int arr[11] = {1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1,0, 1, 1};
        int sequence_count = 0; 
        int loop_count;
        bool continuity = true;
        for(loop_count = 0; loop_count<size; loop_count++)
        {
            if((arr[loop_count]&ONE) == ONE)
            {
                if(continuity)
                    sequence_count++;
                else
                {
                    continuity = true;
                    sequence_count++;
                }           
            }
            else
            {
                continuity = false; 
                sequence_count = 0;
            }
        }
        cout << sequence_count << endl;
```

Comment: Your code isn't runnable as given. Please fix the code so that it is.

Answer (score 3):

I see a number of things that could help you improve your code.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Use only required `#include`s

The code has a line `#include "stdio.h"`s that is not needed.  This clutters the code and makes it more difficult to read and understand.  Only include files that are actually needed.

### Provide `main`

It may just have been a cut and paste error, but this appears to be the contents of a `main` function, even though `main` does not appear.

### Use appropriate names for constants

The constants `size` and `ONE` are a bit too generic and likely to be used elsewhere.  In fact, this code won't even compile using a current version of gcc because of a name clash with `size`.

### Prefer `constexpr` to old-style `#define`

Rather than using a `#define` for `size` the code could use a `constexpr`:

```
constexpr std::size_t ARRAY_SIZE = 11;
```

It doesn't make a lot of difference here, but generally the advantage is that the value has an associated type.

### Declare variables as late as possible

Rather than using the old C-style of declaring all variables at the top of a function, use the modern C++-style and declare variables as late as possible.  Doing so can sometimes help the compiler figure out register allocation, resulting in faster, smaller code.

### Fix your formatting

There are inconsistent spaces at the beginning of lines, inconsistent indentation and inconsistent use of curly braces `{}`.  Being consistent helps others read and understand your code.

### Be careful with signed and unsigned

The code compares an `int` `loop_count` with the size of the array.  Is the size of the array ever going to be a negative number?  Probably not.  Therefore, it would be better to declare `loop_count` to be of type `std::size_t`.

### Fix the bugs

The description says that this code counts ones but the code includes this line:

```
if((arr[loop_count]&ONE) == ONE)
```

The use of the operator `&` in there is doing a binary "and" operation.  That expression would be `true` if the value is `-1` or `5` or any other odd number.  What you probably really want is

```
if (arr[loop_count] == ONE)
```

Also, your program only counts the length of the *last* sequence of contiguous ones.  If you want the maximum length, you'll have to save it.

### Simplify your code

The code contains this sequence:

```
if(continuity)
    sequence_count++;
else
{
    continuity = true;
    sequence_count++;
}
```

But it could be replaced with this simpler sequence:

```
sequence_count++;
```

And then the `continuity` variable isn't even needed.

### An alternative

Here's the code as it might look with all of these suggestions applied:

```
#include <iostream> 

int main() 
{
    constexpr std::size_t ARRAY_SIZE {11};
    constexpr int target_value {1};

    int arr[ARRAY_SIZE] = {1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1};
    unsigned sequence_count = 0; 
    unsigned max_sequence = 0;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == target_value) {
            if (++sequence_count > max_sequence) {
                max_sequence = sequence_count;
            }
        } else {
            sequence_count = 0;
        }
    }
    std::cout << max_sequence << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Unnecessary inclusion

You never use anything from this included header:

```
#include "stdio.h"
```

Also, in C++ you should include the C++ front-end of C headers if available:

```
#include <cstdio>
```

### Array index type

The natural type for array indices in C++ is `std::size_t` (or simply `size_t` in C) because it covers the whole range of possible index values on the current architecture.

```
size_t loop_count;
```

By extension you want the same type to count the length of the longest sequence

```
size_t sequence_count = 0;
```

### Macro vs. function parameter

I don't find the declaration of `ONE` as a macro very useful. If you want your algorithm to work on sequences of arbitrary numbers you should wrap it in a function and supply that number as a function parameter.

```
size_t longest_sequence( const int *array, size_t array_length, int n )
{
  // ...
  return sequence_count;
}
```

### Your code doesn't fit your description

Your code snipped returns the length of the *last* sequence of *odd numbers* – not the longest sequence of a ones! Let's see how we can fix it (including the aforementioned improvements):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::size_t longest_sequence( const int *array, std::size_t array_size, int n )
{
    std::size_t longest_sequence_length = 0,
        current_sequence_length = 0;

    for( std::size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == n)
        {
            current_sequence_length++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (current_sequence_length > longest_sequence_length)
                longest_sequence_length = current_sequence_length;

            current_sequence_length = 0;
        }
    }

    return std::max(current_sequence_length, longest_sequence_length);
}

int main()
{
    static const int arr[] = { 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 };
    std::cout << longest_sequence(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr), 1) << std::endl;
}
```

### Generalization

Since this is C++ you can trivially use a function template to generalize this algorithm to work with arbitrary container/iterator and element types:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <class Iterator, class T>
std::size_t longest_sequence( Iterator begin, Iterator end, T n )
{
    std::size_t longest_sequence_length = 0,
        current_sequence_length = 0;

    for( ; begin != end; ++begin)
    {
        if (*begin == n)
        {
            current_sequence_length++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (current_sequence_length > longest_sequence_length)
                longest_sequence_length = current_sequence_length;

            current_sequence_length = 0;
        }
    }

    return std::max(current_sequence_length, longest_sequence_length);
}


int main()
{
    static const std::array<int, 12> arr2 = { 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 };
    std::cout << longest_sequence(arr2.begin(), arr2.end(), 1) << std::endl;
}
```